# SoX - Mix original signal with effected signal

Tags: command-line, audio, sox

Is there an option in SoX effects processing to mix the wet and dry signals instead of only outputting the wet?

For example, say my effects chain is overdrive into pitch shift:

`sox in.wav out.wav overdrive 0.5 gain -0.5 pitch 700`

Except I don't want the final file to be *just* the shifted signal. I want a mix of the distorted, shifted signal and the distorted, unshifted signal.

Does SoX support this somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you, there is an option especially to mix two signals: `-m`.

```
sox in.wav out.wav mix.wav -m
play mix.wav
```

You can probably do the effect and mix in one command, but I'm just a beginner with sox.

---

You can pipe the output of sox into another sox using the `|command` input
filename syntax, and adding `-p` to make sox output to a pipe in "sox format".
It has the advantage of not using temporary intermediate files.

```bash
sox -m '|sox -v 0.5 in.wav -p overdrive 0.5 gain -0.5' \
       '|sox -v 0.5 in.wav -p overdrive 0.5 gain -0.5 pitch 700' \
   mix.wav
```

Comment: I figured there was probably an option with -m, but I was hoping to do it without splitting the signal into multiple chains.
What you're describing, applied to the original example would be something like:
`sox -m -v 0.5 in.wav overdrive 0.5 gain -0.5 in.wav overdrive 0.5 gain -0.5 pitch 700 out.wav`

But that's pretty ugly for something that I was hoping would be a single extra argument.

Comment: Revisiting this question because 5 years later, I still don't have a solution. But the possible solution in my previous comment does not work because, as the manual says "When combining input files, SoX applies any specified effects (including, for example, the vol volume adjustment effect) after the audio has been combined". I'd really like to do this without exporting to an intermediate file and running multiple SoX commands, but there may be no alternative.

Comment: I added a possibility without intermediate files.

Comment: I actually came here to add more or less that exact comment. Yep. That is the solution